# ASP.NET Core MVC start new thread from an action

Tags: c#, multithreading, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm new to ASP.NET Core, so maybe I'm doing something wrong, here is my issue:

**What do I need:** After loading start page start loading application specific data from Azure Storage in background and show it's status on front-end

**What I did to achieve this:**

```
public ViewResult Index()
{
    var homeModel = new HomeModel();
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        // Some specific work to do...
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(4000);
    });

    return View(homeModel);
}
```

When I run this code front-end view doesn't displayed until Task is not finished, even though it's different managed thread (also I tried to do the same with **new Thread.Start(() => ...);** ).

**My question is:** What it the reason of such behavior? As I said I'm new to ASP.NET Core and I've not worked with ASP.NET of previous versions.

I have some ideas how to work around with this behavior but I want to know the right way to do it and understand the reason :)

**P.S.** I'm using SignalR for updating views from back-end.

Comment: In any case, your approach to application startup jobs is wrong. Have a look at the IApplicationLifetime interface. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45013054/asp-net-core-long-running-task) is a question about it

Comment: Thank you, now I have a clue what to looking for

Comment: @Tewr, please post your comment as the answer to this question so I can mark it as solution

Comment: you might need to fire a GET on DOM ready from javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach to application startup jobs is wrong. Have a look at the [IApplicationLifetime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.iapplicationlifetime?view=aspnetcore-2.0) interface. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45013054/asp-net-core-long-running-task) is a question about it

Answer (score -2):

```
ThreadStart starter = delegate { SomeVoid(somevar); };
  Thread tr = new Thread(starter);
  tr.IsBackground = true;
  tr.Start();
  tr.Join();
```

if need more thread
use with list of thread and loop, sorry if i don't help you

Comment: And you can search code with class backgroundworker.

Comment: As I mentioned I tried to use Thread explicitly, what I need this is the right way to do it. Thank you.