# How do I delay the shutdown of a windows service until an API call has completed?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

I treid creating a `public static bool CanStop { get; set; }` property, which I can set to false before and then back to true after the API call in my `finally{}` block (phew, almost forgot about that).

In any case I am really unsure on how exactly a WindowsService works in handling shutdown requests (eg. when I press stop or restart in ther Windows' Services control panel). Is this really the best way to go about doing this, or am I missing something?

Another thing I'm thinking about it what happens, if the API request takes longer than Windows' timeout on waiting for a service to stop.

Here's my Worker class

```
public class Worker : BackgroundService
{
    //necessary fields

    public Worker(//dependency injected objects)
    {
        //assingment to fields
    }

    public static bool CanStop { get; set; } = true;

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        stoppingToken.Register(PreShutdownCleanup);

        //start application timer

        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000 * 10, stoppingToken);
        }
    }

    private void PreShutdownCleanup()
    {
        while (!CanStop)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }

        //Save application state;

        //stop application timer
    }
}
```

This is still a complex issue for me, as I'm still in the learning process (though do you ever really leave it?...)

Any input is greatly appreceated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Take a look at the answers here [How to create task on startup and stop it on application stop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51705286/how-to-create-task-on-startup-and-stop-it-on-application-stop)

Comment: Thanks, I might just use the StopAsync method instead.